# How do you delete duplicate rows in MySQL without an ID column?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table of option quote history and am trying to remove duplicate columns. Each row of data can be uniquely identified by the combination of these columns: symbol, expiration_date, is_call, strike_price, date. Here is some code from https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/ on how to remove duplicate rows:

```
DELETE FROM contacts 
WHERE 
    id IN (
    SELECT 
        id 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY email
                ORDER BY email) AS row_num
        FROM 
            contacts
        
    ) t
    WHERE row_num > 1
);
```

Unfortunately, I don't have an ID column so this approach doesn't work for me. Here is what I tried:

```
DELETE FROM fake_stock_option_quotes USING fake_stock_option_quotes JOIN 

(
    SELECT symbol, expiration_date, is_call, strike_price, date, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY symbol, expiration_date, is_call, strike_price, date
            ORDER BY symbol) AS row_num
    FROM fake_stock_option_quotes
) dups

ON fake_stock_option_quotes.symbol = dups.symbol AND
fake_stock_option_quotes.expiration_date = dups.expiration_date AND
fake_stock_option_quotes.is_call = dups.is_call AND
fake_stock_option_quotes.strike_price = dups.strike_price AND
fake_stock_option_quotes.date = dups.date
WHERE dups.row_num != 1;
```

This didn't work, however. Here is the table before running the SQL:[image: Table Before]

Here is the table after running the SQL:
[image: Table After]

As you can see, it basically removes all of the duplicate rows and only keeps the rows that didn't have any duplicates to begin with. I was hoping it would remove any duplicates and keep one final unique row after doing so.

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here. If creating a unique ID column is the last resort, I will do that.

Comment: I know in SQL Server I could use row_number() to generate sequential values similar to IDs partitioned by the right columns so I could delete rows where the generated row_number() is greater than 1. I know MySQL > 8.0 will also allow you to generate row_number() values this way, but I don't know (so just a comment) if MySQL maintains references back to the source rows in a way that would allow you to use it with a DELETE statement.

Comment: Please remove the image and add data as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to copy distinct data to another table and then rename the table. Note for all the columns which are not part of the group by clause add an aggregate function like min() or max().

Try,

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES fake_stock_option_quotes WRITE;

CREATE TABLE fake_stock_option_quotes_new LIKE fake_stock_option_quotes;
INSERT INTO fake_stock_option_quotes_new 
    SELECT symbol, expiration_date, min(ask_price) ask_price,min(ask_size) ask_size, is_call, strike_price, date,min(ask_size).... FROM fake_stock_option_quotes group by symbol, expiration_date, is_call, strike_price, date;
DROP TABLE fake_stock_option_quotes;
RENAME TABLE fake_stock_option_quotes_new TO fake_stock_option_quotes;

COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  The same exact result occurred as before.  It looks like I will need to create an ID, unless you have a different idea.

Comment: @GeorgeDouglas see updated answer, but please try on a testing environment first

Comment: I've heard of this approach before but I'm not sure if it will work for me. My production database has a size of 200 GB.  So inserting it from the existing table would take many hours I believe. Am I wrong?

Comment: @GeorgeDouglas `insert into` is faster than `delete from`... so for larger tables this might be the fastest way